# What is the exact way we can print logs using log4net and specflow with .net 6.0

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, log4net, specflow

I want to print logs to separate file in my existing project which created using Specflow with .NET 6.0.

Can someone explain to me how it needs to be done?

I have tried the below steps but not worked.

Added this dependency:

```
<PackageReference Include="log4net" Version="2.0.15" />
```

And this project does not have the app.config or `log4net.config` (I manually created `log4net.config`) and passed configs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
    </configSections>

    <log4net>
        <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%date %level %message%newline" />
            </layout>
        </appender>
        <root>
            <level value="ALL" />
            <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
        </root>
    </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Also in this project, I cannot see `AssemblyInfo.cs` or `Program.cs` file or main method.

I have used the `[BeforeTestRun]` tag to initiate some reports, If need I can use this space if I need to call any method

Comment: Can you post sample of data in log files?  I suspect the data in the log file is xml and NOT well formed.  Well formed XML has only one item as the root element.  When you create log files with XML you add each item to the end of the file and end up with an array of elements at the root.  Most Net XML libraries give error when xml is not well formed.

Comment: @jdweng No log file was generated for the above one. (program was running successfully but no logs getting printed). Also cannot see any log related XML file

Comment: What type project did you build?  A class project will not have a main method.  What is your main project?  Are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: I created a specFlow project: https://docs.specflow.org/projects/getting-started/en/latest/GettingStarted/Step3.html

Comment: To create a new project you do it from the menu File : New Project.  It looks like you are in solution explorer and adding a child project to an existing project.